# Copy files from /sdcard to /System programmatically?

Tags: java, android

I've googled for HOURS and none of the Solutions have worked for me.

OK, So I'm developing this app Specifically for CyanogenMod that Copies a few apps and Sound Libraries to a few Different folders in /System.

After the Files download into a folder in the Internal Storage of the Device `(An LG L90 running CyanogenMod 13), /SDCard/CmSoundMod, it extracts all the zip files into /SDCard/CmSoundMod/unzipped/*Library Name Goes Here*/  with a separate folder for each Library.`

I'm trying to copy an example file from `/SDCard/CmSoundMod/unzipped/SystemFiles/sample.txt to /System` to test it out but All the Methods I know are not working! Ive tried using

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", "cp -r 
sdcard/CmSoundMod/unzipped/SystemFiles/sample text /System");
```

I mounted System RW, and Remounted RO when finished this is just the main code used for copying.

Can some one point me to a piece of code that works for them? (Java)

Thanks!

Comment: The path name should be quoted: `"\"cp -r sdcard/CmSoundMod/unzipped/SystemFiles/sample text\" /System"`